# :even & :odd - resetting after each element styled

Tags: jquery

I have the following function to style list elements:

```
function styleRows() {
    $(".pretty-list li").removeClass("even-row").removeClass("odd-row");
    $(".pretty-list li:even").addClass("even-row");
    $(".pretty-list li:odd").addClass("odd-row");
}
```

I then give any `<ul>` i want styled the 'pretty-list' class and all is fine. However I have various bits of JS that fadeout/remove rows and I then call this function to restyle the rows. The count though continues on through each different `<ul>`, so if there's 2 lists and the first ends on an odd row then the second will start on an even - I want each styled element to start with an odd row.

Is it possible then to tell jQuery/JS to reset the count after it completes each element? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why use JS when you can just use CSS?

Comment: Maybe he needs to support old browsers?

Comment: Sure, but that's why it's a comment rather than an answer. It's also possible that it's an over-engineered solution because they're so used to solving problems with JS. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to split it up like so:

```
$(".pretty-list").each(function () {
    $(this).find("li").removeClass("even-row odd-row")
        .filter(":even").addClass("even-row").end()
        .filter(":odd").addClass("odd-row");
});
```

Using the `each` function there is the important bit. I've also added a few more touches which (if they work -- it's untested) should hopefully make it a bit more efficient.

It's also worth noting that [all modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child) support what you're doing with plain CSS which is much easier to maintain.

```
.pretty-list li:nth-child(2n) {
    /* your 'even' styles */ 
}
.pretty-list li {
    /* your 'odd' styles */
}
```

Comment: It also seems you could tweak the code so you only remove `odd-row` from the even rows, and remove `even-row` from the odd rows. I doubt this would affect efficiency much, though, and it's certainly no shorter.

Comment: Thanks for this, works nicely. I don't claim to be a jquery expert by any means btw, I had no doubt my solution was ever optimal...

Answer (score 1):

if you have multiple `.pretty-lists`, scope on the lists and handle each separately:

```
function styleRows() {
    $(".pretty-list li").removeClass("even-row").removeClass("odd-row");
    $(".pretty-list").each(function() {
      $('li:even', $(this)).addClass('even-row');
      $('li:odd', $(this)).addClass('odd-row');
    });
}
```